# Access a UIViewController class property without casting?

Tags: swift

I have this function in a helper class. It's to show/hide some stuff.

```
   func showHideDetails(controller: UIViewController, isHidden: Bool) {
        ...
        if controller is AddNewViewController {
            let addNewViewController = controller as! AddNewViewController
            addNewViewController.bgButton.isHidden = isHidden
        } else if controller is EditViewController {
            let editViewController = controller as! EditViewController
            editViewController.bgButton.isHidden = isHidden
        }
        ...
    }
```

Is there is a way around to have one if statement, instead of one if statement for each controller? Something like,

```
if controller.hasProperty(bgButton) {
    controller.bgButton.isHidden = isHidden
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Anoher way, We can use singleton to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to cast using `as? ...`, however in order not to do that for all view controllers that have the `bgButton`, you can define a base protocol enforcing all classes conforming to it to have the `bgButton`:

```
public protocol Buttoned: AnyObject {
  var bgButton: UIButton { get }
}

extension Buttoned {

  public func setHideButton(_ isHidden: Bool) {
    bgButton.isHidden = isHidden
  }
}

public class AddNewViewController: Buttoned {
    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var bgButton: UIButton!
    ....
}

public class EditViewController: Buttoned {
    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var bgButton: UIButton!
    ....
}
```

then you can handle the action in the actual view controller like below:

```
func showHideDetails(controller: UIViewController, isHidden: Bool) {
  ...
  if let controller = controller as? Buttoned {
    controller.setHideButton(isHidden)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: So the answer to the question title is no, you need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

In the given scenario to replace your all if with single if means that you should have a common base class or your class conform to same protocol. However type cast still requires. You can use below code to achieve your desired functionality.

Create a protocol BackgroundButton

```
public protocol BackgroundButton {
var bgButton: UIButton { get }
}
```

Conforms all your custom UIViewController with this protocol in Extension like below

```
extension AddNewViewController : BackgroundButton {
var bgButton : UIButton {
    return yourbutton // Use any instance of UIButton from your AddNewViewController 
    }

}

extension EditViewController : BackgroundButton {
var bgButton : UIButton {
    return yourbutton // Use any instance of UIButton from your EditViewController 
    }

}
```

Finally update your method like this

```
func showHideDetails(controller: UIViewController, isHidden: Bool) {
  ...
  if let controller = controller as? BackgroundButton {
controller.bgButton.isHidden = isHidden
controller.bgButton. //Do any thing which you want with your button
  }
  ...
}
```

Hope this will help you to reduce your numbers of if